# Django cron job failing to connect to database on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've a django app running on Elastic Beanstalk with a Postgre database. The app works fine and has no problem  talking to the data base. This is my database settings,

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

However I've a cron job which runs as a custom command and also needs to write an object into the database, here's the custom command,

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        sources = Source.objects.all()
        // write some data
```

This is the configuration file,

```
04_setup_cron:
     command: "cat .ebextensions/crontab.txt > /etc/cron.d/crontab && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/crontab"
     leader_only: true
```

And this is how I set the permissions on crontab.txt

```
*/15 * * * * source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && cd /opt/python/current/app/
&& source /opt/python/current/env && python manage.py parse >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

This cronjob fails, When I log into one of the EC2 instances and try to run this I get the following error,

```
conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

This works fine locally, how do I make it work on the EC2 instance? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from env vars that are not accessibles. 
Try adding to your crontab.txt file this line :

```
*/15 * * * * root . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars && ...
```